# Enable error message in Perl like PHP

Tags: php, perl, error-handling

Is there somehow I can "turn on" error message/error handling in Perl, putting out error message like Apache do by default with PHP? Explaining which line the error is at.

Greetings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you're after [CGI::Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Carp). This module lets you redirect errors and/or warnings to the browser window.

From the doco:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
die "Fatal error messages are now sent to browser";
```

Comment: Perfect! That was what I was after.

Comment: Thee's also `warningsToBrowser` as in: `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);`

Comment: But only use these in development. Turn them off in production. There's a very good reason why the default Apache approach is to display something vague to the user. It's all about security.